# App video preview

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store, xcode6, preview

I'm using Quicktime to capture my app's video preview, when I upload the video to iTunes connect I received the following error:

[image]

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Use imovie > new App Preview project
steps here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300925/cannot-upload-video-to-itunesconnect-the-frame-rate-of-your-app-video-preview-i/42027757#42027757

Answer (score 1):

Once you record video with Quicktime. 
Edit or create app preview with iMovies.

Once you import video to iMovies, there is special option to create app preview video, and then share it as app preview video also.

This should solve your problem and upload app preview to itunes connect.

Thanks
appdemovideo@gmail.om

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [Cannot upload video to iTunesConnect: The frame rate of your app video preview is too high](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300925/cannot-upload-video-to-itunesconnect-the-frame-rate-of-your-app-video-preview-i)

The asker there was able to use a preview version of Final Cut Pro to get a frame rate under 30, which is required for app preview videos.