# Itunesconnect displays error "You haven't made any changes" when Video Preview is added

Tags: ios, video, app-store, app-store-connect, preview

I am trying to add video preview in itunes connect. But when I press Save button it says

> You haven't made any changes.

Also Save button is still available, just like there are some changes. 
[image]

I tried to make other changes. When I add Video Preview, change App Description and press Save, Video disappears but text are saved

Comment: Did you try removing the video and adding it again ?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Tried re-uploading the video about 10 times but get the same error every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. I noticed a small red alert on the video that disappeared in **half second**. There was not enough time to read, so I made screenshot.
[image]

Seems like my video had wrong format, I fixed it with iMovie:

1. Import your video file
2. Select File -> New App Preview
3. Add video to the timeline
4. Select Share -> App Preview
5. Save video file

There is [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300925/cannot-upload-video-to-itunesconnect-the-frame-rate-of-your-app-video-preview-i).

Answer (score 0):

Remember to turn off the background sound for your App Preview when you prepare it in iMovie